# Borderlands 1 GOTY crashing right after splash screen

Tags: borderlands

A friend of mine just got borderlands GOTY, and its been crashing right from the start. Looked around and havnt found much, even in way of "things to try" so thus have asked here.

The game's splash screen comes up, and then it just crashs with the error "Failed to enter MenuMap: Failed to load package 'MenuMap' Please check log for errors" followed by a heck lot of normal error stuff (such as Address = 0x355ac850 (filename not found) GetOutermost() Address 0x75006e ect)

However the error code (after "load package 'MenuMap') seems to scream "I cant find borderlands.exe". (Has a lot of "Cant find file Borderlands.exe")

Does anyone have any useful info about this error, and ways to fix it?

The game works fine on my PC, but not for my friend, and I've even tried running his borderlands files on my pc, and it works fine, however my files will still give the error for him.

Thanks (I'll post screenshots later when I have the chance)

P.S The OS is Windows 7

P.S.S we have tried the following:

- Checked game cache with Steam
- Reinstalled DirectX
- Tried running with files from two other computers (mine and a mates)
- Reinstalled C++ 2008
- Deleted "blob" file (might not be correct name) which let Steam reset its downloads

EDIT:

screenshot:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this on Steam? Or a standalone copy of the game?

Comment: I dont think there is a standalone copy, you have to have steam for both retail and on steam store.... but yes on steam

Comment: Have you tried going into the properties and verifying the integrity of the cache?

Comment: yes, thats the first thing he did, he's also tried using the files of both mine and another mate's. Both have given the error. Also reinstalled Diret X, and ran with the compatiabily settings

Comment: Sadly, that is as far as my troubleshooting PC games goes. =( Just wanted to try and shed some more light on the situation.

Comment: Fair enough, in fact im going to put that in the question right now

Comment: @GarethJones - Does he have steam installed on his main HD? If its on an external(as some people do who have a small SSD), that may be the problem, especially if its running through USB.

Comment: Similar errors in Borderlands have occurred in the past due to poor multicore support.  Try starting the program, then ctrl+alt+delete --> task manager --> right-click borderlands.exe --> set affinity --> set it to a single core.  If that doesn't work, try right-clicking `steamapps\common\borderlands\binaries\borderlands.exe` --> properties --> compatibility --> run this program in compatibility mode (try all the different OS options).

Comment: Also, not that it helps, but that error is not saying *"I cant find borderlands.exe."*  It's saying *"borderlands.exe is calling a Windows function which is looking for a file, but that file can't be found."*  The error doesn't specify which file, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try some of [these](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1448082.html) (I would try Gvaz's fix before a full wipe),  or [this](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=131513) fix. Hopefully you get it fixed!

You could also try renaming `nvcpl.dll` in the `Borderlands\binaries` folder, think I saw that on Reddit a bit back.

Edit: In case threads go down, here are suggested fixes:

> 1. close steam
> 2. rename borderlands folder
> 3. start steam and the download started by itself and finished
> 4. shut down steam again, deleted the new folder after copying over to the old one, renamed old one
> 5. started steam, and I could play the game.

Second fix:

> 1. i deleted all my microsoft visuall version and installed the 4 that are mentioned in this thread:
>      http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/sh...d.php?t=114803
> 2. i switched borderlands language to english
> 3. i have to get rid of the "write-protection" of my steam order everytime before i want to start the game.

Try this last!

> After trying everything i mentioned a few times and other semi-fix attempts i decided to nuke and pave. With a fresh install of windows and 1.40 borderlands works. It seems for one reason or another the patch and/or something working together on my previous install may have corrupted/screwed up one of the two dlls that borderlands error is complaining about (i replaced the first one, couldnt replace the second one as it was write protected).

Comment: Could you copy the potential fixes into your answer, in case those threads ever go down?

Comment: My mate got it working by "turning off his anti virus" or that's what he told me. When I find out more I'll put it here

Comment: @GarethJones well, at least he got it working. Do please follow up with the fix.

Comment: Mate just says all he did was turn the Anti Virus off, and it worked. Also he pointed out that the fix about nuke and pave may be wrong, because the error only occurs on borderlands 1.41 and later

Answer (score 2):

Going through your screenshot image shows two initial problems with Windows and then the rest (Boarderlands.exe) errors are probably an extension of the windows errors since the game can clearly launch before crashing.

The KERNELBASE.DLL is a system file. What you can do is try to make sure that the file is not corrupted. You can find [instructions here off the Microsoft Website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833).

You can also make sure that your .NET frameworks are all up to date. If they are not, you can obtain the standalone installer for [.NET 4 here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) and [.NET 3.5 here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17718).

The MSVCR90.DLL error is tied to a Visual C++ Library (which you have identified), but just to be sure, you can get the [official download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582).

If those are up to date and your graphic drivers are all up to date as well what you can try doing is creating a shortcut for the game on your desktop and running it in compatibility mode on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: -1 Kernelbase.dll has nothing to do with the .Net framework, and Borderlands doesn't require .Net to run.  Also, he already mentioned that he reinstalled the Visual C++ framework.

Comment: I stand corrected, I've adjusted the answer. And I acknowledge that they have re installed the VC Library, but I just wanted to make sure all the bases were covered.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `WillowGame\CookedPC\Maps\Menu_Map\menumap_LOC_INT.upk`

Comment: Why? What does it do? Do you have a source for that? just randomly deleting files might not be smart.